# How could I pass user credential to other services?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, session

I have a node web app (Web A) running in port 8000, where a user can register, log in and can make some posts. Web A has a simple login process like: access user table in its mysql db, check user and password, then creating req.session.user.

Then there's another node web app (Web B) running in port 9000, which handles some different post from WebA and stores data to its own database but uses Web A's user table for user credentials.

I want to access Web A and B's contents freely with a single login from web A, but for some reason can't just merge their code together. How could I make web A's user credentials persist in web B without integrating their codes?

In short,

1. There are two separate node web apps: web A and web B.
2. Web A and B has their own mysql databases, but web B uses web A's user data.
3. When a user logs in to web A, the user should be able to access both web A and B without further authentication.

I've heard about session tables, but can't find a good way to pass them to web B without risking potential security issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you storing in session in the database, just let the client hold sesssion key in cookie.
Then, when access to Web B, using sesssion key in the cookie to refer the session data in database.

Comment: Wouldn't cookies be too vulnerable for such usage?

Comment: Web B would not simply trust the session key. It would have to check Web A for a successful authentication first.

Comment: @Gerard Setho Are there any reference I could use? what should I look into?